# how to get string from EditText to Custom View

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have been working on some custom `View` in an activity. Now let's say we have `EditText` in that activity as well. And I want my custom `View` to get the value in `EditText` when I touch that `View` (which means I want this done in `onTouch` method). The problem is, I have been working on my custom `View` on seperate class, and I can't find a way to get that done. I have initially thought of using `findViewbyId` method to get an id, but it seems undoable. So, any helps or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Here are some codes for my project:

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_nono"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="snacker.nonogramsolver.NonoActivity">

    <snacker.nonogramsolver.Nono /* MY CUSTOM VIEW */
        android:id="@+id/NonoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        ... /*some elements are here, not important for this question*/

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/line_input"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My custom View java file:

```
package snacker.nonogramsolver;

import ...;

public class Nono extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{
... /* some variables */

    public Nono(){
        super(null);
    };

    public Nono(Context context){
        super(context);
        //initializeBoard(10,10);
        mCellWidth = mCellHeight = this.getWidth() / (mWidth);
    }

    public Nono(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        ...}

    ... /* SOME CODES ARE HERE, NOT IMPORTANT FOR THIS QUESTION */

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mXNow = getCol(event.getX());
            mYNow = getRow(event.getY());
            if(mYNow == -1 && mXNow != -1){
                /* THIS IS WHERE I WANT THIS METHOD TO GET VALUE FROM EDITTEXT */
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and my Activity java file:

```
public class NonoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nono);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int width = intent.getIntExtra("width", 5);
        int height = intent.getIntExtra("height", 5);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);
        Nono sdk = (Nono)findViewById(R.id.NonoView);



        sdk.setOnTouchListener(sdk);
        sdk.initializeBoard(width,height);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Nono sdk = (Nono)findViewById(R.id.NonoView);
                sdk.initializeBoard(sdk.mWidth,sdk.mHeight);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Should work by `sdk.findViewById(R.id.line_input)`

Comment: What's your layout for `Nono`?

Comment: @cYrixmorten solved. Well, this is embarrassing. I haven't thought of using R.id in here as well. But, can you tell me why I can use R in here as well? Does R contain of all ids in this package? I am quite new to android, so I was thinking R was being used as local.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin My `Nono` view has no layout, just an `Canvas` to draw on.

Comment: Then save that text when you want to set it on canvas into a private `String` in `Nono` class.

Comment: Glad I could help :) to answer the question, yes the id's registered in layouts are all in the global R file. And no need to be embarrassed, the reason I remembered is that I spend quite some time figuring out the exact same issue at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to cYrixmorten.

I could use `findViewById(R.id.line_input)` method. I haven't thought of using `R.id` here.

Therefore what my code should be would be like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mXNow = getCol(event.getX());
            mYNow = getRow(event.getY());
            if(mYNow == -1 && mXNow != -1){
                EditText sdk = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.line_input);
                String linetext = sdk.getText().toString();
                /* continue my work */
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Once again, I give my thanks.

EDIT: It seems `findViewById` returns null when called with sibling views' id. So it looks like I have to implement external method to get id, not using `findViewById` directly within `CustomView`.